# PatternSyntaxException when splitting string at "*" character

Tags: java, regex

Every time i try to split the string `"hello*world"` using `s.split("*");` I get a PatternSyntaxException.

I have tried using `s.split("\*");` but that gives me another error. Im sure this is something simple.

How do i stop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `split` method takes a regular expression as the argument, not a normal string. The `*` has special meaning in regular expressions. If you want to split on a literal `*`, you have to escape it with a backslash. But the backslash is also an escape character in Java string literals, so you have to escape the backslash too by using two backslashes:

```
s.split("\\*")
```

Answer (score 5):

`*` is a meta-character in regular expressions used as a wildcard quantifier to match zero of more characters

Try using 2 backslash characters

```
s.split("\\*");
```

Comment: I think you should include this: Meta-character `<([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>`

Comment: Or use `Pattern.quote()` or the `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` equivalent.